# How can I incorporate Splunk logging into play framework with java?

Tags: java, logging, playframework-2.0, bigdata, splunk

We have decided to handle log management through SPLUNK. The project is using java-play framework. How do I incorporate SPLUNK logging into play framework with java. Please assist with some example.

Comment: I went through some tutorials and found how to do it using Java. Have no idea how to do it using play framework as no tutorials are available.

Answer (score 0):

Files can be uploaded to Splunk using their web UI, or they can loaded in near-real-time using Splunk's forwarder, which you would install on the server. For simplicity, I will explain how to write a file and then upload it into their web UI manually.

The Play Framework has a logging API implemented with [LogBack.](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/architecture.html)

In your Java application code, implement the `Logger` class. For example:

`import play.Logger;`

`// Log some debug info
Logger.debug("Here is my message.");`

In Play, use the Logging API to place log output into one or more files. This is done using appenders. Make sure your appender adds log data to the files you want to upload to Splunk. When your Logger is executed, the output will be appended to the file(s) you configured.

Then, just download them onto your computer and [upload them with the Splunk web UI.](http://www.splunk.com/view/SP-CAAAG2R)

Here is the Documentation for [logging in Play with Java.](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaLogging)